# Variable (frequency) transformation in R from (0;1) range

Tags: r, data-transformation

I have variable with a range (0;1). I want to do a transformation, so that later I can use this variable as a dependent variable in my multiple linear model. For example, can I use logit transformation? And if I use, what are my Linear model coefficients interpretation with that transformation?

I want to transform, because later I will use this variable as a time series object in ARIMA model and if I use original variable I am getting 95% confidence interval starting from negative values, as I know this variable is in range from 0 to 1 all the time, because it is frequency. I am using R software. I am not sure, but I hear something about "scorse space", but I have no idea what it is.

The idea WHY I want to use linear regression, cause later I want to assess how independent variables affects Y response and I want to do that quantitavely. Not the sign, but also the coefficient value. Cause later I devide Y response into two dependent variables Y_1 and Y_2 and see which one is affected more by independent variables (X1,X2).

You can provide code with any random values from 0 to 1. Thank you for any ideas and thoughts.

My data is in range (0;1), but the interval is not closed. The minimum value is above 0 and the maximum is below 1.

Comment: (deleted earlier comment, I always get dependent and independent mixed up, that's why I prefer "predictor" and "response" ...) logit is difficult if the interval is closed (i.e., if you have actual 0 and 1 values in your data).  arcsin-sqrt is a possibility. I have no idea what "scorse space" is ... typo?

Comment: If by “frequency” you mean a proportion (such as events per a number at risk) then you should investigate logistic regression or Poisson regression. ) If you are only able to use values constrained to the unit interval you might instead consider beta distributed errors (beta regression. )

Comment: @DWin yes, it is proportion. But can I use logistic regression to proportion variable or do I need to do any transformation before? And what is the interpretation of coefficients in logit trasformation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have both the numerator and denominator for cases that were use to create a proportion?

Comment: @DWin yes, I have those values

Comment: So you can apply methods appropriate for count data. You have number of hits or events  and the number at risk so you can properly weight the counts. Use logistic or Poisson regression.